# Golang Make GET Request With Data

Tags: go

Is it possible to do a GET request with data such as:

```
curl -G -v https://someendpoint \
  -d "api_key=myapikey"
```

Which works. In Golang I tried:

```
payload := url.Values{}
payload.Add("api_key", "myapikey")
req, err := http.NewRequest(
    "GET",
    "https://someendpoint",
    bytes.NewBufferString(payload.Encode()),
)
```

But the api key is not being recognised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curl command passes the API key to the server in the URL query string. Here's how to do the same in Go:

```
payload := url.Values{}
payload.Add("api_key", "myapikey")
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://someendpoint?" + payload.Encode(), nil)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a slow morning. I thought perhaps it was possible to pass data in the same way as with POST requests.